# Is using a variable in an onclick worse than using e.target?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

Wondering if there is a performance/memory area I could improve when setting `onclick` listeners to elements.

Example:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.example')
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    btn.classList.add('active');
    btn.onmouseleave = () => {
        console.warn('leave')
    }
})
```

compared to:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.example')
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    e.target.onmouseleave = () => {
        console.warn('leave')
    }
})
```

I would think that using `btn` would take a lot more work as the computer has to save the variable and remember it, whereas e.target uses the event temporarily. **Which one is best for the least amount of memory consumption?**

Comment: `btn` and `e.target` may not always be the same thing https://jsfiddle.net/gecxrsm7/

Comment: _"Which one is best for the least amount of memory consumption?"_ - best is to not worry about absolutely minor stuff like this. Unless you have a use case where this gets used multiple thousand times on the same page, the difference will likely not even be measurable ...

Comment: BTW, the second one seem more generic and you could rename btn or use multiple element.

Comment: Your second version should should just say: `document.querySelector('.example').addEventListener(`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TL;TiM*: **Event delegation*** is better.

### Event `target` vs `currentTarget`

[**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) might **not** be your `btn` Button.
Say the click casually landed on an icon inside of your button `<button type="button">Contact <i class="icon-envelope"></i></button>`, the Event.target would be — your icon!
To get your button Element (on which the **handler is attached**) use [**Event.currentTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

The rule of thumbs is really simple:

- **Always use Event.currentTarget** (even if suggested differently,  unless you really, really know what you're doing)
- Use **Event.target** when in need to do stuff like: getting a closest ancestor (or *self*) from where a click landed. I.e: `if (!evt.target.closest("#popup")) // Click landed outside of #popup. Close the popup` -  or when using **Event delegation** (more on that later).

### Variable vs. Argument performance

There's not much difference in *performance* in using a **variable** holding a **single Element** vs. the **Event argument**, other than perhaps memory and engine implementation.
If `btn` is a **single Element** stored in a variable, it already *is* the currentTarget: `btn === e.currentTarget // always true` therefore it's eventually up to your use case, and that's if you need to **reuse** the `btn` variable in other parts of the app, which would reduce queries to the DOM.
If instead `btns` is a huge [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), such as the one given back by `const btns = ancestorElement.querySelectorAll("selector")`, memory could be a factor.

### `on*` event handlers are arguably bad

`onmouseleave` and other `on*` handlers should **not be used** - unless you're creating (in a really small and readable script) brand new Elements from in-memory, or you intentionally want to override a previously assigned `on*` handler listener of the same *eventName*.

**Use [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead** with the third argument options `{once: true}` (for if an event handler is needed only once).

Third, improved version:

```js
const addActive = (evt) => {
  const elBtn = evt.currentTarget;
  elBtn.classList.add("active");
  elBtn.addEventListener("pointerleave", () => {
    console.log("leave");
  }, {once: true});
};

// Since you're using classes instead of ID,  
// make sure to refer to All of your elements by class,
// and assign an event listener to all of them:

const elsBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.example');

elsBtns.forEach((elBtn) => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", addActive);
});
```

or if the "mouseleave" or "pointerleave" is *always* needed:

```js
const handleClick = (evt) => {
  const elBtn = evt.currentTarget;
  elBtn.classList.add("active");
};

const handleLeave = () => {
  console.log("leave");
};

const elsBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.example');

elsBtns.forEach((elBtn) => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
  elBtn.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleLeave);
});
```

### Event delegation

Say you have thousands of buttons. Storing them all in a variable might consume loads of memory (unless till the value is garbage collected). What better solution do we have?
Instead of a NodeList collection of *N* elements hanging in memory, and assigning to every single one a function handler for a specific Event: target a **single common, static parent or ancestor**:

```
document.querySelector("#commonParent").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const elBtn = evt.target.closest(".example");
  if (!elBtn) return; // Do nothing.

  // ".example" Element was clicked. Do something:  
  elBtn.classList.add("active");
});
```

Event delegation is not only nice because it's *memory friendly*, it also works for current of future Elements added into the DOM.

Also that's the other most used case when using specifically Event.target - but as you can see it's again in combination with the [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) Method.