# is there a way to display child class items from one parent to another parent using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

the link consists of table with p1, p2, p3 and p4 class elements and there associated child class items. which are hidden, this should get displayed when clicked on the parent element.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");

var myFunction = function(ev) {
  var childNodes = ev.target.querySelectorAll('.child');
  childNodes.forEach(child => {
    if (child.style.display == "block")
      child.style.display = "none";
    else
      child.style.display = "block";
  })
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```css
td.child {
  display: none;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p1</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p2</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p3</td>
      <td class="child">p3 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p3 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p4</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

for example: if user has clicked on p3 it should display like this.

```
p1
p2
p3
p3 Some content
p3 Some content
p4
```

Comment: PS: **Always use** `event.currentTarget` (instead of `event.target`) unless in need for `.closest()` or if you really, really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that you were trying to find the **child** elements of the clicked element. However, the elements that you are interested in are **siblings**.

So, you need to get the **parent** of the clicked element and then look for the child elements from that selector.

Specifically:

`ev.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.child');`

See demo:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");

var myFunction = function(ev) {
  var childNodes = ev.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.child');
  childNodes.forEach(child => {
    if (child.style.display == "block")
      child.style.display = "none";
    else
      child.style.display = "block";
  })
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```css
td.child {
  display: none;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p1</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p2</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p3</td>
      <td class="child">p3 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p3 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p4</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add the click listener ([in a delegating manner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72802933/383904)) **to the `TR` parent**
- Inside the listener, make sure the Event was **originated** from `".parent"`
- **Toggle a class** (like i.e: `.is-open`) to the TR element to show the TR's child TD Elements

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);


// Task: Toggle .child on .parent click:

const toggleChilds = (evt) => {
  if (!evt.target.closest(".parent")) return; // Click must originate from ".parent" Element
  evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle("is-open")
};
els(".parent").forEach(elPar => elPar.closest("tr").addEventListener('click', toggleChilds));
```

```css
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }

/* Toggle cells */
td.child { display: none; }
tr.is-open td.child { display: table-cell; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p1</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p1 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p2</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p2 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p3</td>
      <td class="child">p3 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p3 Some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="parent">p4</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
      <td class="child">p4 Some content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```